# location of memcpy definition

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, low-memory

Where is definition of memcpy function located? It is declared in wchar.h where I can find that

```
/* memcpy and memmove are defined just for use in wmemcpy and wmemmove */
```

then I find only the wmemcpy_s.c on my computer and there is a definition of wmemcpy_s function there, which uses `wmemcpy` function which uses `memcpy`.

Where is the definition of memcpy?

Comment: It is in wmemcpy_s.s in assembly.

Comment: There is a definition in src\crt\memcpy.c, but the runtime uses an optimised version. Why do you ask the question? And which version of the runtime are you linking to.

Comment: thanks, I think I have got mixed up. obviously it should be there and I have checked this, but maybe then I was looking for wmemcpy, all in all: many thanks!

Comment: `memcpy` is *declared* in the standard header `<string.h>` (or `<cstring>` in C++).  Its *definition* depends on the implementation, and you ordinarily shouldn't need to care about that.  As long as you have the proper `#include` directive, the compiler and linker should take care of finding it for you.

Comment: ofcourse, I asked because I want to see how it is written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C:\ProgramFiles\MicrosoftVisualStudio10\VC\crt\src\memcpy.c

Answer (score 1):

It depends on compiler being used. For gcc, a generic memcpy is located at libgcc.a, usually a rep movsb. if optimization is turned on the compiler will try to emit inline version instead, and there are multiple versions of built-in memcpy that is optimized for different situations.